# jQuery Active Menu Doesn't Work

Tags: jquery, html

My code doesn't work, when i was add a tag to my html link.

jquery:

```
$('#navbar ul li a').click(function(){
    var index = $(this).index();
    $('#navbar ul li a').removeClass('aktif');
    $(this).addClass('aktif');              
});
```

html:

```
<li><a href="kategori.php?id='.$result->id.'">'.$result->name.'</a></li>
```

Comment: Why are you removing a class and then adding it?

Comment: What are you exactly trying??

Comment: when i click a tag, it must be active class. it is working when the html is: <li><a href="#">'Menü'</a></li>

Comment: What do you mean by that? What does the "aktif" class do?

Comment: aktif mean is "active".

Answer (score 0):

Try this my friend:

```
$('#navbar ul li a').on('click',function(){
    $('.aktif').removeClass('aktif');
    $(this).addClass('aktif');

 }
```